# If/Countif not reading referenced cells and returning the required value correctly

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

In cell A1 I have a drop down list of teacher names to be chosen from, in cell B1 I have a drop down of 1-7 class periods to choose from. Once cell A1 and B1 are populated column A will populate with the students in this teacher’s class (formula 1) and row 2 will be populated with all accommodations students receive (formula 2). The remaining cells will return the value of X if the student in column A receives the accommodation listed in the cell above in row 2 (formula 3). Formula 3 looks at the cells on this sheet and also the cells where the student names and accommodations are listed.

The challenge that I am having is that formula 3 is only returning an X in certain cells despite the student having their accommodations listed in the location that formula 3 checks to reference ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJT6I.png)).

Am I missing a basic typo error in one of the formulas, or is there something else that should be corrected to return an X in all locations where it is necessary? Thank you in advance for your help!

Formula 1 Providing Student Names:
`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('SPED Schedule'!C:C,('SPED Schedule'!G:G='Accommodation List'!A2)*('SPED Schedule'!H:H='Accommodation List'!B2))))`

Formula 2 Providing Student Accommodations:
`=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,FILTER('SPED Schedule'!L:AZ,('SPED Schedule'!G:G=A2)*('SPED Schedule'!H:H='Accommodation List'!B2)))&"</s></t>","//s"))))`

Formula 3 Checking if values in row a :

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$L:$L,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$M:$M,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$N:$N,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$O:$O,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$P:$P,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$Q:$Q,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$R:$R,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$S:$S,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$T:$T,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$U:$U,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$V:$V,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$W:$W,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$X:$X,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$Y:$Y,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$Z:$Z,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AA:$AA,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AB:$AB,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AC:$AC,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AD:$AD,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AE:$AE,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AF:$AF,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AG:$AG,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AH:$AH,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AI:$AI,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AJ:$AJ,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AK:$AK,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AL:$AL,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AM:$AM,D$2)
+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AN:$AN,D$2)+COUNTIFS('SPED Schedule'!$C:$C,$A3,'SPED Schedule'!$AO:$AO,D$2),"x","")
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are using both textjoin and filterxml in formula 2? If you don't use them, would that not result in the same?

Comment: I don’t mean to sound discouraging, but I feel like this is what is often called an “XY Problem.”  We don’t know what your source data looks like, but in trying to reverse engineer these formulas, I sense your approach is more complicated than it needs to be.  O365 has a rich set of array handling functions that would profoundly simplify all these formulas, especially formula 3, but this approach is complicated in a way that makes it impossible for us to understand what the source data must look like.  We’re going to need more sample data to understand what you’re trying to accomplish.